How do I shrink the font size of a markdown table for a powerpoint presentation?
I am preparing a powerpoint slide presentation
---

title: Test
author: Me

---

# Slide 1

- This can be regular font size

# Slide 2

% How do I shrink the fontsize of this table?

| Left align | Right align | Center align |
|:---------------------------| ----------------------:|:----------------------:|
| This | This| This |
| column  | column | column | 
| will | be | aligned |
| left | right | center |


I think you need to link some custom CSS otherwise there is a general font size command but I wouldn't know how to apply it in this context.

For PowerPoint output, you need to create a custom reference.pptx file, modify it in PowerPoint and then supply it to pandoc with pandoc --reference-doc reference.pptx
From the Manual:

You can also modify the default reference.pptx: first run
pandoc -o custom-reference.pptx --print-default-data-file reference.pptx, and then modify custom-reference.pptx
in MS PowerPoint (pandoc will use the layouts with the names
listed above).


There has to be a way to do this in the original markdown file.

@spindoctor Nope. From the manual again: "Pandoc attempts to preserve the structural elements of a document, but not formatting details such as margin size. ". And reference-docs (as opposed to templates) don't support template variables.
